# K8S - RoleBinding - Unable to access secrets from service account cert-manager-webhook-ovh

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks, rbac, kubernetes-secrets, cert-manager

I want to use [cert-manager OVH's webhook](https://github.com/baarde/cert-manager-webhook-ovh) in order to deliver a https wildcard certificate, but I still can't figure out why the cert-manager can't access to OVH credentials secret (required to create a DNS entry in OVH)

The `ovh-credentials` secret has been created on the `default` namespace

The cert-manager is on a `cert-manager` namespace and the `cert-manager-webhook-ovh` is on the `default` namespace

I have a `ClusterIssuer` which is calling the `cert-manager-webhook-ovh`

I have defined a `cert-manager-webhook-ovh:secret-reader` `ClusterRole`

And a `ClusterRole` binding between `cert-manager-webhook-ovh` service account and

the `cert-manager-webhook-ovh:secret-reader` `ClusterRole`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: cert-manager-webhook-ovh:secret-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  resourceNames: ["ovh-credentials"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cert-manager-webhook-ovh:secret-reader
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cert-manager-webhook-ovh:secret-reader
subjects:
- apiGroup: ""
  kind: ServiceAccount
  name: cert-manager-webhook-ovh
  namespace: cert-manager
```

here are my pods

```
➜  alaya-studio git:(main) ✗ kubectl get pods --namespace=cert-manager
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cert-manager-6588898cb4-nfn7p              1/1     Running   1          27d
cert-manager-cainjector-7bcbdbd99f-tgllj   1/1     Running   5          27d
cert-manager-webhook-5fd9f9dd86-csjzq      1/1     Running   0          27d
➜  alaya-studio git:(main) ✗ kubectl get pods
NAME                                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cert-manager-webhook-ovh-77f9c7cc7b-xfdfx             1/1     Running   4          15d
express-59df84c766-8wjxw                              1/1     Running   0          27d
express-59df84c766-l4cf8                              1/1     Running   0          27d
express-59df84c766-w6hbt                              1/1     Running   0          27d
ngingress-ingress-nginx-controller-5586599f89-5fsgn   1/1     Running   0          28d
```

When creating the challenge I have this error

```
  Type     Reason        Age              From          Message
  ----     ------        ----             ----          -------
  Normal   Started       9s               cert-manager  Challenge scheduled for processing
  Warning  PresentError  5s (x3 over 7s)  cert-manager  Error presenting challenge: secrets "ovh-credentials" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:cert-manager-webhook-ovh" cannot get resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "cert-manager"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicating to ServiceAccount `cert-manager-webhook-ovh` of `default` namespace. You have given permission to the the ServiceAccount of `cert-manager` namespace.

```
secrets "ovh-credentials" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:cert-manager-webhook-ovh" cannot get resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "cert-manager"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, so I have changed the namespace to `default`  in the `CusterRoleBinding` for the ServiceAccount `cert-manager-webhook-ovh` but now the error has changed into: **Warning  PresentError  5s (x4 over 30s)  cert-manager  Error presenting challenge: secrets "ovh-credentials" not found**

Comment: Can you please ensure the secret exist? Probably cert-manager log will help.

Comment: Ok that's better I just moved the ovh-credentials secret into the namespace `cert-manager` and put the namespace `cert-manager` in the role binding. I still have an error but I move forward, I will check my creds : **Warning PresentError 3s (x3 over 5s) cert-manager Error presenting challenge: OVH API call failed: GET /domain/zone/alaya.studio/status - Error 403: "This credential is not valid" ** So I suppose it is just about my credential and consider the issue fixed. Thank you